# getting wierd json format in http get method - nodejs/express

Tags: node.js, json, express

I'm trying to get data from keepa - I'm getting a weird JSON format that any JSON extension cannot read.
in postman, the request working just fine and I'm getting readable JSON.
what am I missing here?

```
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");
const decompressResponse = require("decompress-response");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get("/", function(req, res){

res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post("/", function(req, res){

console.log(req.body.asinId);
const query = req.body.asinId;
const apiKey = "MY_API_KEY";
const url = "https://api.keepa.com/product?key="+ apiKey +"&domain=1&asin="+ query;

const options ={
      methode:"GET",
      hearders: {
      "Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8",
      "Accept-Encodeing":"gzip",
      }
}

https.get(url,options, function(response){
response = decompressResponse(response);
console.log(response.statusCode);
console.log(response.headers);
var data;

response.on("data", function(chunk) {
if (!data) {
data = chunk;
} else {
data += chunk;
}

console.log(data);

});
});
res.send("server is running");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume your are talking about your `console.log(data);` inside the data event callback of response.
This is because you haven't read all the data yet.
`response.on("data", callback)` gets called for each chunk that you received and decompressed.
To get the finished data put the console.log inside of the end event callback:

```js
const express = require("express")
const https = require("https")
const decompressResponse = require("decompress-response")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser")

const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

app.get("/", function (req, res) {

    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html")
})

app.post("/", function (req, res) {

    console.log(req.body.asinId)
    const query = req.body.asinId
    const apiKey = "MY_API_KEY"
    const url = "https://api.keepa.com/product?key=" + apiKey + "&domain=1&asin=" + query

    const options = {
        methode: "GET",
        hearders: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
            "Accept-Encodeing": "gzip",
        }
    }

    https.get(url, options, function (response) {
        response = decompressResponse(response)
        console.log(response.statusCode)
        console.log(response.headers)
        var data

        response.on("data", function (chunk) {
            if (!data) {
                data = chunk
            } else {
                data += chunk
            }
        })

        response.on("end", function () {
            console.log(data)
        })
    })
    res.send("server is running")
})
```